# Where is the favicon?

Tags: wordpress, favicon

This might be a silly question... I usually add my Favicon's in the  area of the my site, but a previous developer has set this website up.
I usually add code a bit like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

The site has a favicon but I can't find where its being created, or even where its being held in the WordPress theme: https://www.sbccanford.co.uk/

Any ideas? I've popped the URL to the website above.

Thanks,
Meg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that was added in the customizer. Go to Admin Dashboard -> Appearence -> Customize -> Site identity. and its there.

[image]